# How to decide the parantheses in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am a little bit confused about putting the parantheses in scheme. The following example:

```
=>(define foo1 (lambda (n) (+ n 1)))
=>(foo1 ((lambda () 5)))

=>value:6
```

Gives the result 6. But i am surprised why this did not give an error. Here is how i thnik it should be computer: First the (lambda () 5) expression is computed and it returns 5. Now we an remove its parantheses:

```
=>(foo (5))
```

And now this should be invalid since we do not use parantheses for the parameters while calling a function. But it gives no error. Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright! Finally figured out what's going on here.

This statement actually evaluates to 5:

((lambda () 5))

Try it in your REPL.

The inner part (lambda () 5) creates a procedure. The outer paranthesis pair '(', ')' invoke the function. Obviously that makes it return 5!

Comment: You are right, it is really weird, or i think it is weird since i am new to scheme. Thank you

Comment: Haha. Its been a while since I've touched scheme. This question spurred my curiosity enough to open up my dusty DrRacket again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Scheme makes no fundamental distinction between code and data. Why do I mention this? It's because Lambda's return is always either a function or an error, that is it returns code rather than simple data.   Any other function that returns a function is going to behave in the same way.